# Could not complete the operation due to error 80020101 ONLY in IE8

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, internet-explorer-8

I have a dialog which appears on clicking an item on the main page.
Here is the javascript code which is used to open the dialog.

```
function openPopup(userId) {
              var url = '@Url.Action("UserDetail", "Manage")';
              url = url + "?userId=" + userId;
              $("#resultDialog").load(url, function () {
                  $("#resultDialog").dialog("open");
              });
```

**EDIT BEGIN:**

My **resultdialog** code is as follows:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateUser", "ManagerUser", FormMethod.Post, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "resultDialog" }))
 {
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
     @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
     <div id="right">
         <p style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #666; text-align: left; padding: 0px 0 0px;">&nbsp;</p>
         <div class="box1-bord">
             <div style="border: 1px solid #f2f2f2; height: auto; background-color: #e4ebe4; padding: 5px;">
                 <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
                     <tr>
                         <td width="21%" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #666; text-align: left; padding: 10px;">Disable User</td>
                         <td width="39%" align="left">
                             @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsDisabled)

                         </td>
                         <td width="40%" align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td colspan="3" style="border-top: #fff 1px dashed;">&nbsp;</td>
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                         <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; color: #666; text-align: left; padding: 10px;">User ID</td>
                         <td>
                             @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserID, new { @readonly=true,style="width: 300px; height: 30px; line-height: 28px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 5px; font-size: 12px; color: #666; border: solid 1px #ccc;"})
                             @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserID)
                         </td>
                         <td align="left">&nbsp;</td>
                     </tr>

                     <tr>
                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                         <td align="right">
                             <button onclick="submitForm(this);"  class="button2" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666666; text-align: center;"><a href="Javascript:void(this);">UPDATE</a></button>
                             <button onclick="submitForm1(this);" class="button2" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px; color: #666666; text-align: center;"><a href="Javascript:void(this);">Reset Password</a></button>
                         </td>
                         <td>&nbsp;</td>
                     </tr>
                 </table>

             </div>
         </div>

         <div style="clear: both;">&nbsp;</div>
```

In the above code **@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.IsDisabled)** 
should display the check mark. IsDisabled is boolean

**EDIT END**

This does not work in IE8  and gives me the error. 
I checked

1. All my code to see if I have placed a comma in an incorrect position as someone suggested.
2. Verified for **//** and removed too.

There are posts which says if it is a Ajax call it throws such error. If that is so, what should be the solution? If this is not where the error is then could anyone provide me direction to troubleshoot more or a possible solution???

Comment: can you post your "resultDialog" razor code?

Comment: @Golda - I have edited my previous post to include the code for resultDialog

Comment: Have you tried with partial view?. In partial view it works fine. Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try This

**Partial View**

```
@model <Model Name>
Is Disabled:  @Html.CheckBoxFor(model=>model.IsDisabled)
```

**View**

```
<div id="resultDialog">
  @Html.Partial("PartialName", DemoManager.function()) // Place partial view inside dialog
</div>
```

Its works fine in Fire Fox as well as internet explorer

Comment: **var url = '@Url.Action("UserDetail", "Manage")'** . In this Usertdetail action method does return a partial view...